# ¿Como creo un layout estilo hoja de papel?

Tags: java, android

estoy creando una app de notas y nesecito que el layout tenga un estilo parecido a este[image: estilo]

las lineas horizontales serian un Listview de cada nota que yo tenga, hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código para el layout pero quiero saber si existe una mejor forma de hacerlo.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<View
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="0.5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E93F67"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/linea2"
    android:layout_width="0.5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E93F67"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linea2"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"></ListView>
```

[image: lo que tengo hasta ahora]

Comment: Sería muy guarro ponerlo como imagen de fondo y ajustar la separacion de lineas  y el margen para que encaje con las lineas horizontales del fondo ?

Comment: Yo haría algo similar, pero en lugar de hacer el margen fuera del listview, lo haría parte del layout item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#f6ff9e"
        android:id="@+id/lv" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#40c1ed"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view2"/>


    <View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#E93F67"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#E93F67"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>


    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Elemento" 
        android:id="@+id/tvElemento"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Haz un adapter personalizado, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861738/11063757) un ejemplo. Aunque con muchos elementos se ve bien, pero no es lo mismo cuando sean pocos.

También se me ocurre que sea el fondo como lo quieres(el fondo amarillo y las lineas rojas) solamente que sin las lineas azules, eso se pondría con el divider del listview

```
  android:divider="#40c1ed"
  android:dividerHeight="4dp"
```

Aqui el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!